# rake task being invoked multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, rspec-rails

I have a strange problem with testing my rails tasks. When I'm running all the tests for my rake tasks they are being invoked multiple times, but when I run only one test file everything is suddenly working. Here is an example code:

rake task

```
namespace :after_party do
  desc 'Deployment task: create_users_on_another_app'
  task create_users_on_another_app: :environment do
      ...some code
      AppClient.post(some_url, some_payload, some_header)
      ...some more code
      AfterParty::TaskRecord.create version: '20190620160110'
    end
  end
end
```

rspec test

```
describe 'create_users_on_another_app' do
  before do
    allow(AppClient).to receive(:post).and_return(some_response)
  end

  it "creates users" do
    expect(AppClient).to receive(:post).with(some_url, some_data, some_header)
    puts "JUST BEFORE INVOKING THE TASK: "
    Rake::Task['after_party:create_users_on_another_app'].invoke

    puts "DONE"
  end
end
```

in the console output i can see something like this:

```
> JUST BEFORE INVOKING THE TASK: 
> Running deploy task 'create_users_on_another_app'
> Running deploy task 'create_users_on_another_app'
> DONE
```

so the task was invoked two times.

I have no idea why this is happening and I'm 100% sure I'm not invoking it in my code twice. I'm suspecting that either it is some rake configuration for rspec that I'm missing or the gem for rake tasks that I'm using - `after_party`.

I'm having hard times debugging it, tried using `show-stack` with `binding.pry` while I'm in the rake task that is causing the issues but didn't manage to see at what point additional rake task was being fired.

anyone has seen such issue before?

EDIT: stack trace of running show-stack command inside `it` block, just before the `invoke` rake task:

```
=> #0  <main> 
   #1 [block]   block in run <Byebug::PryProcessor#run(&_block)>
   #2 [method]  run <Byebug::PryProcessor#run(&_block)>
   #3 [method]  resume_pry <Byebug::PryProcessor#resume_pry()>
   #4 [method]  at_line <Byebug::PryProcessor#at_line()>
   #5 [method]  at_line <Byebug::Context#at_line()>
   #6 [block]   block (2 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #7 [block]   block in run <RSpec::Core::Example#run(example_group_instance, reporter)>
   #8 [block]   block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks()>
   #9 [block]   block in with_around_example_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_example_hooks()>
   #10 [block]   block in run <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run(position, scope, example_or_group)>
   #11 [block]   block in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #12 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #13 [block]   block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter> 
   #14 [method]  instance_exec <RSpec::Core::Example#instance_exec(*args, &block)>
   #15 [method]  execute_with <RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook#execute_with(example, procsy)>
   #16 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #17 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #18 [block]   block (3 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #19 [method]  perform_enqueued_jobs <ActiveJob::TestHelper#perform_enqueued_jobs(?, ?)>
   #20 [block]   block (2 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #21 [method]  instance_exec <RSpec::Core::Example#instance_exec(*args, &block)>
   #22 [method]  execute_with <RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook#execute_with(example, procsy)>
   #23 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #24 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #25 [block]   block in run <RSpec::Retry#run()>
   #26 [method]  run <RSpec::Retry#run()>
   #27 [method]  run_with_retry <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#run_with_retry(opts=?)>
   #28 [block]   block (2 levels) in setup <self.setup(UNKNOWN) (undefined method)>
   #29 [method]  instance_exec <RSpec::Core::Example#instance_exec(*args, &block)>
   #30 [method]  execute_with <RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook#execute_with(example, procsy)>
   #31 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #32 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #33 [method]  run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #34 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run(position, scope, example_or_group)>
   #35 [method]  with_around_example_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_example_hooks()>
   #36 [method]  with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks()>
   #37 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Example#run(example_group_instance, reporter)>
   #38 [block]   block in run_examples <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run_examples(reporter)>
   #39 [method]  run_examples <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run_examples(reporter)>
   #40 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run(reporter=?)>
   #41 [block]   block (3 levels) in run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #42 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #43 [method]  with_suite_hooks <RSpec::Core::Configuration#with_suite_hooks()>
   #44 [block]   block in run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #45 [method]  report <RSpec::Core::Reporter#report(expected_example_count)>
   #46 [method]  run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #47 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Runner#run(err, out)>
   #48 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args, err=?, out=?)>
   #49 [method]  invoke <RSpec::Core::Runner.invoke()>
   #50 [top]     <top (required)> 
   #51 [eval]    <main> 
   #52 [main]    <main>
```

also attaching stack trace from inside the rake task itself:

```
=> #0  <main> 
   #1 [block]   block in run <Byebug::PryProcessor#run(&_block)>
   #2 [method]  run <Byebug::PryProcessor#run(&_block)>
   #3 [method]  resume_pry <Byebug::PryProcessor#resume_pry()>
   #4 [method]  at_line <Byebug::PryProcessor#at_line()>
   #5 [method]  at_line <Byebug::Context#at_line()>
   #6 [block]   block (2 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #7 [block]   block in execute <Rake::Task#execute_without_bugsnag(args=?)>
   #8 [method]  execute <Rake::Task#execute_without_bugsnag(args=?)>
   #9 [method]  execute_with_bugsnag <Rake::Task#execute_with_bugsnag(args=?)>
   #10 [block]   block in invoke_with_call_chain <Rake::Task#invoke_with_call_chain(task_args, invocation_chain)>
   #11 [method]  mon_synchronize <MonitorMixin#mon_synchronize()>
   #12 [method]  invoke_with_call_chain <Rake::Task#invoke_with_call_chain(task_args, invocation_chain)>
   #13 [method]  invoke <Rake::Task#invoke(*args)>
   #14 [block]   block (2 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #15 [block]   block in run <RSpec::Core::Example#run(example_group_instance, reporter)>
   #16 [block]   block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks()>
   #17 [block]   block in with_around_example_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_example_hooks()>
   #18 [block]   block in run <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run(position, scope, example_or_group)>
   #19 [block]   block in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #20 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #21 [block]   block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter> 
   #22 [method]  instance_exec <RSpec::Core::Example#instance_exec(*args, &block)>
   #23 [method]  execute_with <RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook#execute_with(example, procsy)>
   #24 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #25 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #26 [block]   block (3 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #27 [method]  perform_enqueued_jobs <ActiveJob::TestHelper#perform_enqueued_jobs(?, ?)>
   #28 [block]   block (2 levels) in <top (required)> 
   #29 [method]  instance_exec <RSpec::Core::Example#instance_exec(*args, &block)>
   #30 [method]  execute_with <RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook#execute_with(example, procsy)>
   #31 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #32 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #33 [block]   block in run <RSpec::Retry#run()>
   #34 [method]  run <RSpec::Retry#run()>
   #35 [method]  run_with_retry <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#run_with_retry(opts=?)>
   #36 [block]   block (2 levels) in setup <self.setup(UNKNOWN) (undefined method)>
   #37 [method]  instance_exec <RSpec::Core::Example#instance_exec(*args, &block)>
   #38 [method]  execute_with <RSpec::Core::Hooks::AroundHook#execute_with(example, procsy)>
   #39 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #40 [method]  call <RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy#call(*args, &block)>
   #41 [method]  run_around_example_hooks_for <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run_around_example_hooks_for(example)>
   #42 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Hooks::HookCollections#run(position, scope, example_or_group)>
   #43 [method]  with_around_example_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_example_hooks()>
   #44 [method]  with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks <RSpec::Core::Example#with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks()>
   #45 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Example#run(example_group_instance, reporter)>
   #46 [block]   block in run_examples <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run_examples(reporter)>
   #47 [method]  run_examples <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run_examples(reporter)>
   #48 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.run(reporter=?)>
   #49 [block]   block (3 levels) in run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #50 [block]   block (2 levels) in run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #51 [method]  with_suite_hooks <RSpec::Core::Configuration#with_suite_hooks()>
   #52 [block]   block in run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #53 [method]  report <RSpec::Core::Reporter#report(expected_example_count)>
   #54 [method]  run_specs <RSpec::Core::Runner#run_specs(example_groups)>
   #55 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Runner#run(err, out)>
   #56 [method]  run <RSpec::Core::Runner.run(args, err=?, out=?)>
   #57 [method]  invoke <RSpec::Core::Runner.invoke()>
   #58 [top]     <top (required)> 
   #59 [eval]    <main> 
   #60 [main]    <main>
```

EDIT 2: added more info

I've checked what would happen if I place `binding.pry` like that (and inside the rake task as well)

```
  it "creates users" do
    expect(AppClient).to receive(:post).with(some_url, some_data, some_header)
    binding.pry # no1 before rake task invokation
    Rake::Task['after_party:create_users_on_another_app'].invoke
    binding.pry # no3 after rake task invokation
    puts "DONE"
  end
```

below after party rake task code

```
namespace :after_party do
  desc 'Deployment task: create_users_on_another_app'
  task create_users_on_another_app: :environment do
      ...some code
      binding.pry # no2 inside the task
      AppClient.post(some_url, some_payload, some_header)
      ...some more code
      AfterParty::TaskRecord.create version: '20190620160110'
    end
  end
end
```

and the output was that code execution stopped at `no1`, then we went into the rake task and stopped at `no2`, afterwards the task was ran AGAIN (so again stopped at `no2`) and afterwards it was stopping at `no3`

Comment: Can you share both stack traces, when you pause at the line `puts "JUST BEFORE INVOKING THE TASK: "` twice?

Comment: @Grzegorz added the stack trace - first one is from inside the `it` statement. Second is from inside the rake task itself (every time the rake task is being invoked the stack trace appears the same)

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page. There's `Running deploy task 'create_users_on_another_app'` message showing in the console. Set up a breakpoint there (you should pause there twice), and let's compare stack traces from both of those pauses.

Comment: when I set breaking point inside `it` statement it only gets called once (the result is the first stacktrace). When I set the breaking point inside the rake task itself it gets called twice (that's the second stacktrace, when I'm checking this stacktrace in to second invokation of rake task it is the same as in the first one).

Comment: "(that's the second stacktrace, when I'm checking this stacktrace in to second invokation of rake task it is the same as in the first one)." This is extremely hard to believe. Are you 100% sure? As in: I saved both stack traces, and diffed them and there was no difference whatsoever? They have to have different paths leading to "#13 [method]  invoke <Rake::Task#invoke(*args)>"

Comment: the paths leading to #13 are the same. They are identical and I'm receiving the same output repeatedly when not running this test in isolation. I've tried checking how come the task is being invoked multiple times (Even though the code in `it` block is ran only once) but I can't locate from where it can be called. That's why I was thinking whether this is some bizzare configuration issue. I've added more details to my initial question after some more investigation

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but resolved it by checking how the tasks were loaded in apparently unrelated tasks spec files.
In another spec file, the tested task over there was loaded as

```rb
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

which actually loads all tasks.
So in the spec file I was working on, I had of course to require the task I wanted to test; so that would load this task a second time only when I would load the whole test suite.

Replacing this line with

```rb
Rake.application.rake_require 'tasks/your_task_file'
```

and changing the task call with `.execute` instead of `.invoke` did the trick. `.execute` does not load the `:environment` though, so if you need it you might want to find a way to do so

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you load your rake task in the tests

```
# File1
dscribe 'some test 1' do 
  before do
   Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r }
  end
  ...
end

# File2
dscribe 'some test 2' do 
  before do
   Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r }
  end
  ...
end
```

Is not so good in one single test run of this two files. Rake seems to register the rake tasks twice. You need to take care that the rake task just get registered once like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   confige.before :suite do
     Dir.glob('lib/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| load r }
   end
end
```

This should work because the test registration is only done once. Or use somehow `require`. `require` checks if a file is already registered.

Comment: I don't have access to that particular codebase (and can't confirm whether that would solve the issue) but this is a valuable insight, thanks!